# Minification not using latest files

Tags: css, bundling-and-minification

I'm using Asp.Net's Bundling and Minification feature and I have a bundle of CSS files in a staging environment where debug is set to false to emulate production. For some time now I've had an error in asp.net's minification function in both staging and production environments:

```
Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(11479,6713): run-time error CSS1030: Expected identifier, found '['
(11479,6718): run-time error CSS1031: Expected selector, found '='
(11479,6718): run-time error CSS1025: Expected comma or open brace, found '='
```

This is what I see on Chrome's DevTools. I fixed the issues and tested it locally with debug turned off. This message went away and the files were successfully minified. However when I publish the css files to the staging server I still get the error. When I look at the CSS, prettyfied by Devtools, I notices that my changes are not there.

I've checked the usual suspects: wrong file published, published to wrong server and none of it is the case. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12324888/976764) the bundle is supposed to update the cache whenever there are changes to the files. But this isn't happening for some reason. Any ideas?

Another weird thing is that when I remove the offending file from the bundle, it is still served up by the minifier.

Answer (score 1):

In your error above (11479,6713): 11479 is the line number and 6713 is the character offset. So you need remove the whole comment where this error is appear.
I think you have both .css and .min.css file included. In that case please check this, its explained clearly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28470331/publishing-a-website-is-not-updating-my-css-bundles)

Comment: I already stated that I fixed the issues indicated and I am not including both css and min files. Asp.net minification does not output *.min files, it creates a resource of all the css files in the bundle, minified.